# Tooltip with a link on it (displayed on hover or on click)?

Tags: hover, tooltips

I have a tooltip with a link on it. 
[image: tooltip with a link]

What is the best practice of displaying this tooltip: on click or on hover?

I will still need a clicked version for tablet. Should the popup have a close icon in this case, or can I rely on tapping outside?

Thank you!

Comment: If you show the tooltip on hover, how is the user going to click on a link in the tooltip?

Comment: @Luciano, he could hover over, leave a sticky tooltip/popover open and have a close button technically.

Comment: Poor design do not do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover indicates quick passive intake of information. If they need to do something, such as click on a link then it needs to stay open and it should be on click with a close option.
It is too hard for people to take actions in purely hover states.